# 1st order linear DE with step function input

Tags: functions, laplace-transform

the 1st order linear equation is:

$y'(t) + \frac D M y(t) = f(t)$

with constants:

$D = 100kg/s$

$M = 1000kg$

$f(t) = Fu(t)$  <-- that's Force x the unit step function

an initial condition:

$y(0) = 20.8m/s$

the input is a step function scaled by the Force $F$ ($Fu(t)$)
we need to solve the DE and then find the Force needed to make the final velocity $27.8m/s$.

also a block diagram  with the Laplace transform:

$f(t) \longrightarrow {\frac 1M \over (s + \frac DM)}$

thank you!

here's what i have so far...

first i integrated the linear function.

$y'(t) + .1 y(t) = .001f(t)$

using $mu$ in the linear DE and the initial condition y(0) = 20.8

$y(t) = .01 + 20.79 e^(-.1t)$  that's e to the power of -.1t

the problem is i can't figure out what to do with the right side of the equation.  the step function scaled by force.  i need help integrating the right side.  $Fu(t)$

i need to solve the equation to a point where i can input a constant value for the force in order to aim for the target velocity of 27.8m/s.

Comment: thank you for helping with the edit Mahdi.  i'll put in where i'm at so far.

Comment: $f(t) = Fu(t)$ yes.  the Laplace of the step being the integral of $u(t)e^(-st)$ ?  i don't know why the -st won't superscript.

Comment: $u(t)e^{-st}$  Yes, the input is a step function scaled by the force F.  $f(t) = Fu(t)$.  Once solved i need to find a Force that will yield a new given final velocity.

Comment: F is constant insofar as once it is applied to the object it will remain the same, in order to achieve the final velocity.  Also, thank you for helping me Azmoti.

Comment: It just says "choose F such that the final velocity is 27.8m/s".  The only time given is when the velocity is 20.8 at t=0.  But the next part of the problem says "plot the velocity y(t) versus time.  Your axis should go from 0 to 100 sec."  So I guess we will use 100s as the final time.

Comment: I didn't realize that until just now.  I don't know why it wasn't a part of the first question.

Comment: Oops yes i did i apologize.

Comment: I apologize, Azmoti.  Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given:

$$\tag 1 y'(t) + \frac D M y(t) = \dfrac{1}{M}f(t)$$

where:

- $D = 100kg/s$
- $M = 1000kg$
- $f(t) = Fu(t)$, Force $\times$ Heaviside unit step function
- Initial Condition (IC): $y(0) = 20.8m/s$

Rewriting $(1)$ yields:

$$\tag 2 y'(t) + \dfrac{1}{10} y = \dfrac{F}{1000} u(t)$$

Taking the Laplace Transform of $(2)$ yields:

$$\mathcal{L}\left(y'(t) + \dfrac{1}{10} y = \dfrac{F}{1000} u(t)\right) = s y(s) - y(0) +  \dfrac{1}{10} y(s) = \dfrac{F}{1000 s}$$

We want to group the $y(s)$ term on the LHS side and everything else on the RHS, so we have:

$$y(s)\left(s + \dfrac{1}{10}\right) = y(0) + \dfrac{F}{1000 s} = 20.8 + \dfrac{F}{1000 s}$$

So we have (that last part is a partial fraction expansion):

$$\tag 3 y(s) = \dfrac{20.8 + \dfrac{F}{1000 s}}{s + \dfrac{1}{10}} = \dfrac{0.01 (F+20800 s)}{s (10 s+1)} = \left(\dfrac{20.8-0.01F}{s+0.1} + \dfrac{0.01 F}{s}\right)$$

Now, we need to find the Inverse Laplace Transform of $(3)$, so we have:

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}~(y(s)) = y(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}~\left(\dfrac{20.8-0.01F}{s+0.1} + \dfrac{0.01 F}{s}\right) = 0.01 \left(F-(F-2080) e^{-t/10}\right)$$

So, we have:

$$y(t) = 0.01 \left(F-(F-2080) e^{-t/10}\right)$$

Now, we need to find $F$ such that the final velocity is $27.8~m/s$. We are given a final time for this velocity at $t = 100$, so we would have:

$$y(100) = 0.01 \left(F-(F-2080) e^{-10}\right) = 27.8 \rightarrow F =  2780.03$$

Thus, we have:

$$y(t) = 27.8003-7.0003 e^{-t/10}$$

A plot of this is:

[image]